# Axes on RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I'm defining a bunch of regions and I would like verify them visually by plotting.

Unfortunately, when I use RegionPlot3D the axes don't show up (though according to the docs they should be on by default). How do I turn them on?

Example:

```
pyramid[d_, h_] := 
 ImplicitRegion[
  And @@ {-d z/2 <= x <= d z/2, -d z/2 <= y <= d z /2, 
    0 <= z <= h}, {x, y, z}]

RegionPlot3D[pyramid[1, 1]]
```

This is in version 10.3

Comment: `RegionPlot3D[pyramid[1, 1], Axes -> Automatic]`?

Comment: @Xavier yes, it seems so. Thanks.